# Using pytesseract for Hebrew language in tables

Tags: python, databricks, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I've been trying to use `pytesseract` for the Hebrew language, from tables (I have my own ways to detecting the tables, for this question I'll focusing on the chars detections), the platform I'm using is [databricks](https://www.databricks.com/) with a notebook (`.ipynb`).

I'm using the following command:

```py
languages_ = 'heb+eng' # I also tried only 'heb'

data = pytesseract.image_to_data(image,lang=languages_, output_type='data.frame', config=special_config)
```

The `config` options I tried are:

```py
8) --psm 12 --oem 1 --dpi 3000
7) --psm 12 --oem 2           
6) --psm 12 --oem 1           
5) --psm 12 --oem 0           
4) --psm 12                   
3) --psm 6                    
2) --psm 5                    
1) --psm 11
```

> I got the best result with option number (6).

The problems I still have is the following:

1. Multiple time I see that it can't distinguish between the `,` and the `.` characters
2. For some reason for numbers it recognize number 2 and 3 as 3
3. Multiple time I see that if a cell have multiple values (even just 2) it will seperate it for multiple columns per word (it does not occur on every row so its a problem because the next rows are good so its impossible to organize it)
4. Sometimes (not on every row and column) it adds another column with some of the cells containing the character | , I can only imagine it detect the column border as a character sometimes
5. I've noticed that also different colors image and different boldness are making it to give different results too (the above problems are the most mutual problems I had)

I saw this GitHub issue [Hebrew issues #82](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/langdata/issues/82) and multiple other links to articles and repos but still no luck in my quest.

> I am unable to supply with an example table since the information I
> use is sensitive, but if it's a must comment and I'll make something
> up

If any other information is needed, please comment and I'll add it.

Comment: Anyone? Please, any help will be appreciated!